# Spinner won't work with OnItemSelectedListener

Tags: android

I have this form which contains textinput and spinner, the content of the form depends on the database so it's generated programmatically.

Some of my field, be it a text input or a spinner, are mandatory.
So some spinner are marked red if they have no selection, what I'm trying to do now it to put them back to their original color once the user has selected something.

I have no problem with the edittext field but the spinner will not trigger the onItemSelected event when the user change the spinner selection.

Xml of a spinner, an "item", those items are then inflated and put in a gridview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="item"
            type="com.test.mymy.ui.models.GrotGridviewItem" />
    </data>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="@{item.label}"/>
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:entries="@{item.values}"
            android:selectedItemPosition="@={item.spinnerPosition}"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

In my activity:

```
GroGridviewAdapter champsadapter = new GroGridviewAdapter(activity, grotFields, grotGenerator.getIsChampObligatoire());
GridView champsGridView = binding.formulaire;
champsGridView.setAdapter(champsadapter);
```

the getView method of the GroGridviewAdapter, where the magic happens :

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    final GrotGridviewItem grotGridviewItem = grotGridviewItems.get(position);
    int typeNumber = getItemViewType(position);

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(
            Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    ViewDataBinding binding;
    if (typeNumber == GrotGridViewItemTypeEnum.TEXT.getNumber()) {
        binding = GrotFieldTextBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false);
        final GrotFieldTextBinding grotFieldTextBinding = (GrotFieldTextBinding) binding;
        EditText editText = grotFieldTextBinding.value;

        //set it red or transparent when the page first load
        if (null != redAtStart.get(grotGridviewItem) && redAtStart.get(grotGridviewItem)) {
            editText.setBackgroundColor(GrotColorsEnum.RED.getIntValue());
            champIsRed.put(grotGridviewItem.getChampEntity(), true);
        }

        editText.addTextChangedListener(makeTextWatcher(grotFieldTextBinding, grotGridviewItem));
        
    } else if (typeNumber == GrotGridViewItemTypeEnum.SPINNER.getNumber()) {
        binding = GrotFieldSpinnerBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false);
        GrotFieldSpinnerBinding grotFieldSpinnerBinding = (GrotFieldSpinnerBinding) binding;
        Spinner spinner = grotFieldSpinnerBinding.spinner;
        Log.i("####", "Adding listener to spinner");
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                Log.i("##spinner##", String.valueOf(position));
                if (spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() != -1) {
                    spinner.setBackgroundColor(GrotColorsEnum.TRANSPARENT.getIntValue());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                Log.i("##spinner##", "nothing");
            }

        });

        //set it red or transparent when the page first load
        if (spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() != -1) {
            spinner.setBackgroundColor(GrotColorsEnum.TRANSPARENT.getIntValue());
            champIsRed.put(grotGridviewItem.getChampEntity(), false);
        }
        if (null != redAtStart.get(grotGridviewItem) && redAtStart.get(grotGridviewItem)) {
            spinner.setBackgroundColor(GrotColorsEnum.RED.getIntValue());
            champIsRed.put(grotGridviewItem.getChampEntity(), true);
        }


    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("type N°" + typeNumber + " does not exist");
    }

    if (null == view) {
        view = binding.getRoot();
    }

    binding.setVariable(BR.item, grotGridviewItem);
    return view;
    }
```

What did I do wrong?
Do you need more code?